# Unable to run project in Eclipse due to ADB errors

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I am very new to Eclipse and I'm using Eclipse Mars on Windows 7. When I tried to run a project in Eclipse, it failed and showed the messages:

> The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred.
>
> You must restart adb and eclipse.
>
> Please ensure that adb is correctly located at.....

I searched for solutions on the website. I tried to use the command prompt to kill adb, but it displayed:

> server not running

Then I typed `adb start-server` which did not work and displayed among something else:

> adb out of date... killing...

I also tried to use `adb nodaemon server`. However, it resulted in error message:

> cannot bind to tcp 5037 : no error

I could not find anything though I searched on the web for the `no error` part.

I used the `netstat -ano | findstr 5037`, but none of them showed *listening*.

I think it has to do with the `no error` part. But when I tried to run the project again, it still failed.

Comment: go to task manager and kill adb process...then restart the eclipse...restart automatticaly starts the adb..and then it should work

Comment: I can't find the adb process in the task manager...

Comment: there must be something called adb.exe in the processes tab of the task manager

Comment: I have deleted it ages ago already...

Comment: Check if replacing ADB files of Android player by ADB files of Android SDK helps according to advise at [ADB out of date error when attemtping to run UITest](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26519/adb-out-of-date-error-when-attemtping-to-run-uitest).

Comment: Have you tried to Clean and rebuild the App?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I copied everything to my Notebook and it worked.